# Is there a way to create a new variable every loop in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a loop to reuse the same dropdown list up to 20 times, but can be as few as 1 time. I want to be able to loop it and have a new variable assigned to the dropbox each time to be used later.

So far this is what I have tried:

```
Column {
    for (i in 1..20) {
        ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
            expanded = expanded,
            onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded },
            Modifier
                .padding(vertical = 8.dp)
                .width(200.dp)
        ) {
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalTextInputService provides null) {
                TextField(
                    readOnly = true,
                    value = songVar,
                    onValueChange = { songVarChanged(it) },
                    label = { Text("Song$i:") },
                    trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded)  },
                    colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
                    modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor()
                )
            }
            ExposedDropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            ) {
                options.forEach { selectionOption ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = { Text(text = selectionOption) },
                        onClick = {
                            songVarChanged(selectionOption)
                            expanded = false
                        },
                        contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding,
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What this resulted in was currently 12 boxes, each labeled with a different number, but they share the same value in the box. If I change one, it changes all. Like so:
[image: Test build of a multi box application in Android]

Edit:
This is what I was using **songVar** and **songVarChanged** for:

```kotlin
// Declared in activity
val options = rememberSaveable {
    listOf(_<list of options here>_)
}
var songVar by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf("")
}

// Calling the composable and sending values
    Column(Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp)) {
        ExposedDropdownMenuSongs(
            songVar,
            songVarChanged = { newSongVar ->
                songVar = newSongVar
            },
            options = options,
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide the relevant parts of your code (namely what `songVar` and `songVarChanged` are), the following example just shows how this is possible in general. You'll need to adapt that to fit with the rest of your code.

There is no need for a `CompositionLocalProvider`, that can be removed entirely (The `TextField` is still needed though).
The key part is that `songVar` is declared inside the loop. Then the following will work:

```
var songVar by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

TextField(
    readOnly = true,
    value = songVar,
    onValueChange = { },
    modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor(),
)

ExposedDropdownMenu(
    expanded = expanded,
    onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
) {
    options.forEach { selectionOption ->
        DropdownMenuItem(
            text = { Text(selectionOption) },
            onClick = {
                songVar = selectionOption
                expanded = false
            },
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added more context to my original question. I need to be able to keep track of all selections because I need to use them in other composables. Would it be better to have all of the options done manually? I was trying to create a new box with the same list only after the previous box was populated with a choice. Up to 20 times.